# Is it possible to run custom initialisation code ONCE for each thread created in boost::asio::threadpool

Tags: c++, boost, floating-point, threadpool, boost-asio

I've noticed that boost::asio::threadpool does not copy threadlocal state such as the floating point environment into the child threads. This caused subtle bugs in my application. My current solution is to make a call [fesetenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feenv) on every task that is posted to the threadpool.

So my current workflow is

```
boost::asio::thread_pool m_threadPool;
fenv_t curr_env;

/* Save current environment. */
fegetenv(&curr_env);

/* Post tasks to the threadpool but set the fp environment before doing the real work */
boost::asio::post(m_threadPool, [&](){
    fesetenv(&curr_env);
    task();
});
```

Even though **fesetenv** is probably fast I'd rather have this run once per thread on the pool. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [`thread_local`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local) and [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) seems like a good fit, except that "does not copy threadlocal state" bit you've already discovered.

Comment: there's no injectable thread initialisation code in an asio:: thread_pool, which is a shame. however it would be fairly trivial to write your own.